Can the DynNom function in R create a dynamic nomogram from a Cox model with time varying coefficients
Recently, I learnt about DynNom function which allows one to generate a dynamic nomogram. When I attempted to generate a dynamic nomogram from a Cox model allowing for time varying coefficient after using the survSplit function, an error reading “start/stop notation not supported”.
Below is a sample dataset and code to replicate the error.

# Load necessary libraries
  library(survival)
  library(rms)
  library(DynNom)

# Example: Simulated dataset
  set.seed(123)
  n <- 200
  data <- data.frame(
    id = 1:n,
    age = rnorm(n, 60, 10), # Age as a covariate
    sex = sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE), # Sex as a binary covariate
    start = 0,
    stop = rexp(n, rate = 0.1), # Random survival times
    event = sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE) # Random event indicator
   )

# Split dataset to incorporate time-varying covariates
  data_split <- survSplit(
    Surv(start, stop, event) ~ ., 
    data = data, 
    cut = quantile(data$stop, probs = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)), # Time split points
    episode = "time_period" # New variable for time periods
)

# Cox model with time-varying coefficients
  cox_model <- coxph(
    Surv(start, stop, event) ~ age + sex + time_period:age + time_period:sex,
    data = data_split
  )


# I tried the code below

# Dynamic nomogram
  dd <- datadist(data_split)
  options(datadist = "dd")

  dyn_nom <- DynNom(cox_model, data_split)

And an error note above was returned.
Any suggestions about how a dynamic nomogram can be generated with data from survSplit?
Thank you very much for your time.

It might be worth contacting the maintainer (Amirhossein Jalali a.jalali2@nuigalway.ie) for qualified advice on this issue - the assumptions/maths behind time varying coefficients is complicated (e.g. time dependance survival vignette), and the error is clear (the dynnom function isn't designed to handle that input), so you might be 'stuck' unfortunately @Richard

If you are hoping for something new, then you should define in much better detail what the word “dynamic“ means in this context. That word in used in a variety of questions and it sometimes means you want user input to result in “something” but it’s rarely clear “what”.

Thank you for the question @IRTFM. Dynamic as used in this question means the ability of the user to update covariate values

Thanks @jared_mamrot for the suggestion. I will contact the maintainer.
